# Running docker image gives MemoryError

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ec2, rdf

I tried to run the docker images on AWS EC2. Following is the dockerfile which creates the docker images.

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:latest
WORKDIR /workspace
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y coreutils \
    && apt-get install -y findutils \
    && apt-get install -y wget \
    && apt-get install -y python3 \
    && apt-get install -y python3-pip \
    && apt-get install -y tar
COPY requirements.txt /workspace/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN wget https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fairseq/models/roberta.large.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzvf roberta.large.tar.gz
COPY work /workspace/work
COPY pipeline /workspace/pipeline
COPY scripts /workspace/scripts
COPY resources /workspace/resources

ENTRYPOINT ["/workspace/scripts/run_all_22.sh"]
```

When I ran the docker image, I got following MemoryError. It happens when parse the rdf graph. But the script itself runs well on my local machine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  Filpipeline/preprocessing/preprocess_claims_relativepath.py", line 226, in <module>
    main()
  File "/pipeline/preprocessing/preprocess_claims_relativepath.py", line 215, in main
    claims = parse_aifdocs(root, args.aif_path, doc_out_json_dir)
  File "/pipeline/preprocessing/preprocess_claims_relativepath.py", line 34, in parse_aifdocs
    aif_graph.build_graph(str(inpath), fmt = "ttl")
  File "/aif/rdf_graph.py", line 174, in build_graph
    graph.parse(graph_path, format=fmt)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rdflib/graph.py", line 1330, in parse
    parser.parse(source, self, **args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/notation3.py", line 1943, in parse
    p.loadStream(stream)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/notation3.py", line 454, in loadStream
    return self.loadBuf(stream.read())  # Not ideal
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/notation3.py", line 460, in loadBuf
    self.feed(buf)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/notation3.py", line 473, in feed
    s = octets.decode("utf-8")
MemoryError
```

I tried to specify memory swap when running the docker image but didn't help. I also noticed that some answers said MemoryError may happen when install 32 bit python on 64 bit system, but I am not sure if it is the case for docker. Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: Does your local machine have more memory than your EC2 instance?

Comment: what kind of EC2 instaqnce is it? I mean, you already will spent a lot of memory loading the model Roberta Large, when the RDF graph itself is also large ...